# Find the interval on which $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (1+\frac12+\frac13+...+\frac1n)\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}$ converges uniformly.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (1+\frac12+\frac13+...+\frac1n)\frac{\sin(nx)}{n}$

I've found that it doesn't converge "uniformly" on whole $\mathbb R$.

But my attempt seemed not to be promising.

Could you give me any advice to proceed?

Edit: Where does it converge uniformly? I knew that it does not converge uniformly on $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that on the interval $[\delta, 2\pi-\delta]$ with $0 < \delta < 2\pi$ we have

$$S_m(x) =\left|\sum_{n=1}^m \sin nx\right| = \left|\frac{\sin \left(\frac{mx}{2} \right)\sin \left[\frac{(m+1)x}{2} \right]}{\sin \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}\right| \leqslant \frac{1}{\sin \left(\frac{\delta}{2} \right)},$$

and the partial sums of $\sin nx$ are uniformly bounded.

Since, in addition, $H_n/n$ is monotonically and uniformly convergent to $0$, the series is uniformly convergent by the Dirichlet test on any interval or union of intervals without a limit point at $2k\pi$ where  $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2):

The question has been modified.

The series $\sum a_n \sin(nx)$ converges at every point if $a_n$ decreases to $0$. This can be found on p. 112 of Fourier Series by Edwards. In this case it is fairly easy to see that this condition is satisfied. Hence the series converges on the whole of $\mathbb R$.

A necessary and sufficient condition for uniform convergence is $a_n$ decreases and $na_n \to 0$. [Same reference for this result also].  This condition is not satisfied here  so the convergence is not uniform on $\mathbb R$. By periodicity it does not converge uniformly on any interval of length $2\pi$ or more.

EDIT: looking at the  proof of Theorem 7.2.2 in Edward's book I find that the series does not converge uniformly on any interval of the type $[-a,a]$ with $a>0$.

Comment: Oh I've found that it doesn't converge "uniformly" on $\mathbb R$....

Comment: I changed it to the question asking uniform convergence.

Comment: @glimpser A necessary and sufficient condition for uniform convergence is $a_n$ decreases and $na_n \to 0$. This condition is not satisfied here  so the convergence is not uniform.

Comment: So now what I'd like to find is the interval on the above series uniformly converges.